# Roll $5$ dice. Record the product. How many rolls are required so that the recorded products generate a square number?

Tags: probability

$5$ fair dice are rolled. The product of the displayed numbers is recorded (lets call it M1). Dice rolled again and product is recorded again (M2). How many rolls are required so that the products (M1 * M2) generate a square number?

Its been a long time since I did probabilities so I started going about this the long way. Generated an Excel spreadsheet with all possible $7776$ outcomes and came to the conclusion that there are $126$ distinct values for the product after the first roll ($7776$ being the largest).

And that's where I became stuck and lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Each trial is independent?  You aren't adding the totals or anything?  Then all you have to do is to compute the probability $p$ that you have a square outcome on a single trial and then the answer is $\frac 1p$.

Comment: Thanks lulu, but unfortunately it is not that simple (or perhaps I could have explained it better). Dice is rolled the first time. The product is recorded (lets assume it is M1). Dice rolled again, and M2 is recorded. M1 * M2 need to produce a square number. How many rolls are required? I suspect this has something to do with Binomial, but I can't get around it.

Comment: I still don't understand.   If you toss the five dice $n$ times do you compute $\prod_{i=1}^nM_i$?  Something else?  If it is the iterated product in question, you might find it easier to just sample.  Otherwise, you can do it with Markov chains.  Just note that each state is determined by a triple $(a,b,c)$ where the iterated product is $2^a3^b5^c$.  All you care about is the parity of $(a,b,c)$ so there are only $8$ states.  Just work out the transition probabilities and then use standard methods.

Comment: What kind of product is to be computed after the 3rd roll?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the details for the procedure outlined in [lulu's](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/252071/lulu) second comment. If the current value of the product is $\ 5^a3^b2^c\ $ then the state of the Markov chain is $\ \gamma\beta\alpha\ $, where $\ \gamma=c\hspace{-0.2em}\pmod{2}\ $, $\ \beta=b\hspace{-0.2em}\pmod{2},$ and $\ \alpha=a\hspace{-0.2em}\pmod{2}\ $.  For the throw of a *single* die, the probabilities of each of the eight states are given by the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\text{throw}&1\text{ or }4&2&3&6&5\\
\text{state, }s&000&001&010&011&100&101&110&111\\
\hline
p_1(s)&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&\frac{1}{6}&0&0&0\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
The probability $\ p_n(s)\ $ of obtaining state $\ s\ $ when $\ n\ $ dice are thrown can be calculated recursively from the following convolution:
$$
p_n(s)=\sum_{t=000}^{111}p_1(t)p_{n-1}(t\oplus s)\ ,
$$
where $\ \oplus\ $ denotes the bitwise xor operation (i.e. componentwise mod $2$ addition).

The values of $\ p_5\ $ are given in the following table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
s&000&001&010&011&100&101&110&111\\
\hline
p_5(s)&\frac{139}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Thus, the initial state of the Markov chain, after the first throw, is the probability row vector
$$
\pi(1)=\pmatrix{\frac{139}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}}\ .
$$
Whenever the chain enters state $\ 000\ $, the product at that time will be a square, and the goal has been reached.  This state is therefore absorbing:
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(S_{n+1}=s\left|
 S_n=000\right.\big)=\cases{1&if $\ s=000$\\
 0&otherwise.}
$$
Otherwise the transition probabilities are given by
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(S_{n+1}=s\left|\right.S_n=t\big)=p_5(s\oplus t)\ ,
$$
for $\ t\ne000\ $.  Therefore the transition matrix of the chain is
$$
\Pi=\pmatrix{&000&001&010&011&100&101&110&111\\
000&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
001&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{139}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}\\
010&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{139}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{35}{324}\\
011&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{139}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{107}{972}\\
100&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{139}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}\\
101&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{139}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}\\
110&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{139}{972}&\frac{137}{972}\\
111&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{35}{324}&\frac{107}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{137}{972}&\frac{139}{972}}\ .
$$
After $\ n\ $ throws the state of the chain will be the probability row vector $\ \pi(n)=\pi(1)\Pi^{n-1}\ $, and the probability that a square has been reached at or before that time is the first entry of that vector.

If $\ t_s\ $ is the expected number of throws needed to reach state $\ 000\ $ from state $\ s\ $, then $\ t\ $ must satisfy the equations
\begin{align}
t_{000}&=0\\
t_s&=1+\sum_{k=000}^{111}\Pi_{sk}t_k\\
&=1+\sum_{k=001}^{111}\Pi_{sk}t_k\\
&=\Pi_{s\,000}+\sum_{k=001}^{111}\Pi_{sk}\big(t_k+1\big)\ \ \text{ for }\ s\ne000\ .
\end{align}
The solution of these equations is given in the following table
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
s&000&001&010&011&100&101&110&111\\
\hline
t_s&0&\frac{970}{121}&\frac{970}{121}&\frac{970}{121}&\frac{1752}{211}&\frac{212414}{25531}&\frac{212414}{25531}&\frac{212414}{25531}\\
\hline
\end{array}\ ,
$$
and the expected number of throws for the chain to reach the absorbing state $\ 000\ $ is
\begin{align}
1+\sum_{s=000}^{111}\pi(1)_st_s&=\sum_{s=000}^{111}\pi(1)_s\big(t_s+1\big)\\
&=8\ .
\end{align}